# Row Autosize property not working of Table Layout?

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I am working on a windows application, in which i am using a table layout panel, in this table layout i have created 5 rows and that is autosize, now dynamically i am adding 4 radio buttons and text for radio button is a bit long but the problem is it is behaving like absolute and not showing the full text.

I am adding radio button like this-

```
       for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            rbtn1 = new RadioButton();
            rbtn1.Name = "rbtn" + (i + 1);
            rbtn1.Text = "A jogger running at 9 kmph alongside a railway track in 280 metres ahead of the engine of a 120 metres long train running at 45 kmph in the same direction. In how much time will the train pass the jogger?";//ansList[i].ToString();
            rbtn1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            rbtn1.Font = new Font("Verdana", 10);
            tableLayoutExamPanel.Controls.Add(rbtn1, 1, i + 8);
        }
```

I am working on this from last 10 hours.

Need help, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I realise this is an old question, however:

1. Set the dock style of each RadioButton to DockStyle.None
2. Set AutoSize = True for each RadioButton.

Autosize won't work if you have a dock style set. Make sure you the above is true for each child control on the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the radio buttons autosize property to true.

And remember that a control in a TableLayoutPanel cell always shrinks to fit in the cell until its MinimumSize is reached.

P.S. You could also try setting the AutoSizeMode property to GrowOnly.

See [MSDN for more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171729%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

EDIT: try this...

```
.RowStyles.Clear();
.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
```

Comment: i have tried radio button autosize property to true and also AutoSizeMode property to GrowOnly for table layout but it's not working.

Comment: how can we avoid this- "That a control in a TableLayoutPanel cell always shrinks to fit in the cell until its MinimumSize is reached."

Comment: @Denny It seems obvious that... at which point should it not shrink? i.e. set a MinimumSize for the controls you don't want to shrink?